# Saving Jquery sortable values to mysql Database using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I seen this solution for someones problem but what I dont understand is what should be written in the saveSortable.php file.

Anyone shed some light?

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="1">elem 1</li>
    <li id="2">elem 2</li>
    <li id="3">elem 3</li>
    <li id="4">elem 4</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
            $.get('saveSortable.php', {order:newOrder});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you just need to search on Google.. First result: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have something like this:

```
//do database connection here

$orders =  explode(',',$_GET['order']);
foreach ($orders as $key=>$value) {
$query = "UPDATE `tabel_name`
SET sort_order = {$value}
WHERE id = {$key}";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the values from the GET so you need code as follows:

```
$values = $_GET('order');
```

Then save your values to the database by iterating through the $values array.

Answer (score 0):

Just explode them by `,`:

```
$values = $_GET['order'];
$list = explode(',', $values);

foreach($list as $item){
    // do something with $item - 1    
}
```